# Trying to update user with membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, membership

I tried to update user in several ways.

First try:

```
ExtendedMembershipProvider provider = new SimpleMembershipProvider();
var user = Membership.GetUser("benn");
user.IsApproved = true;
provider.UpdateUser(user);
```

Second try:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser("benn");
user.IsApproved = true;
Membership.UpdateUser(user);
```

The exception on the first try was:

> You must call the `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` method before you call any other method of the `WebSecurity` class. This call should be placed in an *_AppStart.cshtml* file in the root of your site.

Although I call it in *global.asax*

The exception on the second try was:

> specific method not supported.

What should I do?
thanks.